# Layers missing at project start-up

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-3

Does anyone know what is the problem? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Your layers were either deleted or moved to a different location, or your access rights were revoked.

Answer (score 2):

This happen when you change the data location, A QGIS document only register the path to access your data but not the actual data so if you displace your data in another location you get this message telling you that QGIS can't find the data in the previous location.

To fix it you have to double click on the red old path and provide the new data location